# How to return values inside double array(double[]) which is inside ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<double[]>` as below:

```
[{x1,x2,x3} , {y1,y2,y3} , {z1,z2,z3} , . . . ]
```

I need to bring out each array {, , } and get sum of them.

I tried several ways but got no result..

```
for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size() ; i++ ) {
arrylist . get(0) = something
```

but i cannot implement the reset..

Comment: Which ways did you try?

Comment: What exactly is giving you problems? You should be able to do this with a simple nested [`enhanced for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`The for-each loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to travel (*iterate*) your list and the arrays inside the list.

Try this :

```
    List<double[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double[] doubleArr : list) {
        double sum = 0.0d;
        for (double val : doubleArr) {
            sum += val;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the array is : " + sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i < arrayList.size() ; i++ ) {
     for (int j=0; j < arrayList.get(i).length; i++)
         sum += arrayList.get(i)[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your tried code , I found you are facing difficulties with loops. Learn them.

```
double result=0.0;
for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
 double[] currentArray=   yourArrayList.get(0);
  for(double dou : currentArray){ //again on internal array
      result += dou;
   }
}
```

// do something with result